# Neo4j - How to formulate this query using executeCypher using params

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I have a query like this

```
start n = node:node_auto_index('ids:"123", "456" ... ') return n
```

Here 123, 456 is a list of keys as a single param {list}. Now when I try to write this in Java

```
String q = " START n=node:node_auto_index('key:{ids}') return n  "
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("ids", keyList); // keyList is a list of strings
```

But somehow calling `graphstoreclient.executeCypher(q, map)` fails with parse error, can you point me to any documentation / correct syntax on this.

PS - This query works fine on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're supplying a lucene query string, parameterize the entire string:

```
String q = " START n=node:node_auto_index({ids}) return n  "
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("ids", keyList);
```

keyList should now look like `ids:"123", "456" ...`